# split array line by line in perl then use regex to match values to find difference

Tags: regex, perl

I have text file the consist of:

```
ID_REF  IDENTIFIER  GSM88918    GSM88914    GSM88919    GSM88915    GSM88917    GSM88913    GSM88916    GSM88912
IG_2146_3437147_3437252_rev_at  /start=3437147 /end=3437252 /direction=+ /description=intergenic region nan nan 43.7    50.1    nan nan nan 26.5
IG_415_642550_642629_fwd_at /start=642550 /end=642629 /direction=+ /description=intergenic region   2212.9  1795.1  1112.6  942.6   614.2   753.4   402.6   535.2
.
.
more of this lines
```

my script will read in the data, calculate the differences between the biofilm (which are GSM88912, GSM88913, GSM88914, and GSM88915) from suspension (which are GSM88916, GSM88917, GSM88918, and GSM88919) measurements.

I am planning to put it in a hash with key of gene name which is IG_2146_3437147_3437252_rev_at. then have the 4 result difference i.e. GSM88916 - GSM88912 = diff1 in the hash as its values.but I only get the first values when doing the regex.

```
 open(IN,"GDS2768.txt")||die $!;
 my @arrayOfLines = <IN>;
 #print @arrayOfLines;
 close(IN);

 # initialize variables
 my $line;
 my %hashGeneName;
 my $geneName;
 my @geneNames;
 my $GSM88918;
 my $GSM88914;
 my $GSM88919;
 my $GSM88915;
 my $GSM88917;
 my $GSM88913;
 my $GSM88916;
 my $GSM88912;

 foreach $line (@arrayOfLines){
chomp $line;
#if ($line =~ /IG(\w+)\s.+?region\s(\w+|\d+\.?\d*)\s(\w+|\d+\.?\d*)\s(\w+|\d+\.?     \d*)\s(\w+|\d+\.?\d*)\s(\w+|\d+\.?\d*)\s(\w+|\d+\.?\d*)\s(\w+|\d+\.?\d*)\s(\w+|\d+\.?\d*)\s/){
$geneName = $1;
$GSM88918 = $2;
$GSM88914 = $3;
$GSM88919 = $4;
$GSM88915 = $5;
$GSM88917 = $6;
$GSM88913 = $7;
$GSM88916 = $8;
$GSM88912 = $9;
print "$geneName : $GSM88918, $GSM88914, $GSM88919, $GSM88915, $GSM88917, $GSM88913, $GSM88916, $GSM88912\n";
}
```

}

```
   OUTPUTS:
   IG_2146_3437147_3437252_rev_at : nan, nan, 43.7, 50.1, nan, nan, nan, 26.5
```

I want it to print all values in the line that match in the array. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider just `split`ting each line on whitespace:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    next if $. == 1;
    my ( $geneName, @vals ) = (split)[ 0, -8 .. -1 ];
    print "$geneName: @vals\n";
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output on your dataset:

```
IG_2146_3437147_3437252_rev_at: nan nan 43.7 50.1 nan nan nan 26.5
IG_415_642550_642629_fwd_at: 2212.9 1795.1 1112.6 942.6 614.2 753.4 402.6 535.2
```

The elements of the array `@vals` are the values you need for calculating differences.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am getting: Use of uninitialized value $vals in split at /tmp/execpad 86f038a4019b/source-86f038a4019b line 13, <> line 4. 
on the lines that doesn't have the $gene and $vals. how can I add something like if $gene exist in a line I can do the hash and split?????

Comment: @CatRodriguez - There may be an issue in your dataset.  To accommodate for this possibility, note that `if $geneName and @vals` was added to the `print` line.

Comment: Hi Kenosis. I am still getting the Use of uninitialized value $vals[4] in join or string at /tmp/execpad-ecb0183593db/source-ecb0183593db line 9, <> line 2.on the line that don't have the IG_2146_3437147_3437252_rev_at: nan nan 43.7 50.1 nan nan nan 26.5. I really don't know what's going on. I am really new to perl.

Comment: @CatRodriguez - It's evident that when the line is `split`, some values are missing, thus the "uninitialized value" warning for `$vals[4]`: `split` didn't initialize it.  Are you using `$vals[4]` in a subtraction operation?  It sounds like some lines contain incomplete biofilm or suspension data.

Comment: I have been getting  "uninitialized value" warning  since the lines I am parsing have : (1) b1391_at paaD 442.6 486.6 nan 324.9 nan 320.8 219.9 nan <----enter---->
(2) IG_2146_3437147_3437252_rev_at /start=3437147 /end=3437252 /direction=+ /description=intergenic region nan nan 43.7 50.1 nan nan nan 26.5 <----enter---->in my text file, in which my $geneName can be b1391_at or IG_2146_3437147_3437252_rev_at. Is there a condition I can say if there is 13 number of index I can do this: my ($geneName, @vals) = (split)[0,6 .. 13];and if 9 this: my ($geneName, @vals) = (split)[0, 2 .. 9];

Comment: @CatRodriguez - See my updated answer.  The `(split)[ 0, -8 .. -1 ]` notation [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)s the list that `split` generates, returning the first and last eight elements of the list.  Thus, it effectively handles the different sized data rows.  The original answer, of course, assumed uniform data rows.